# Configure IIS 7 to handle *.JSP requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I need to serve *.jsp requests on my iis 7
I want to run MVC 4 application to handle those requests
How do i configure my IIS and MVC to handle those requests and not return error 404?

**edit**
I am not trying to run JSP engine on my IIS, I just want to process the request in my MVC app

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I want to process the request in my MVC app and not run a JSP engine. Just need help to configure the iis & mvc to handle these requests

Answer (score 0):

I got it
I created a class that implements `IHttpHandler`
and added this line to the website web.config
`<add verb="*" path="*.jsp" type="NAMESPACE.CLASS_NAME, ASSEMBLY_NAME"/>`